# Implementation of language_attributes function

Tags: themes

I am reverse engineering *how to make wordpress themes*. For that, I opened its files and found language_attributes() function. I went to function.php to find it but it was not there. Any ideas where can I find its implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This function is defined in `wp-includes/general-template.php`. Use a real IDE for development to [find the source of a function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47573/73) faster.

If your document is not XHTML and the content is runnung from left to right you don’t need this function. A simple …

```
echo 'lang="' . get_bloginfo( 'language' ) . '"';
```

… does everything you need.

For no obvious reasons the function creates a `dir="ltr"` – that’s the [default value](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-dir-attribute), no need to write it into every page.